# HTML5 video player using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, playlist

I am trying to build a client side solution for a HTML5 video playlist, I cannot use AJAX or XML for this project and it is causing me some issues.

Basically I have a video tag loading in one video and then an unordered list called 'playlist' that has all my videos in it. I have it working so that it can play either Mov's or Ogv's out of one page as a playlist but I cannot get a fallback working within the list. I am a little stuck, I have read that browser sniffing is old practice but cannot come up with a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code so far -

```
**HTML**
    <!-- /playlist -->

<div class="span2">
     <ul id="playlist">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="disc_content/video/retro_photography_effects/film_burn.mov"/><img src="images/video/image1.jpg" style="margin-bottom:21px;"></a>
            <a href="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/101/ogvs/holga.ogv"><img src="images/video/image1.jpg" style="margin-bottom:21px;"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="disc_content/video/retro_photography_effects/holga.mov" /><img src="images/video/image2.jpg" style="margin-bottom:21px;"></a>
            <a href="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/101/ogvs/holga.ogv"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="disc_content/video/retro_photography_effects/holga.mov" /><img src="images/video/image2.jpg" style="margin-bottom:21px;"></a>
            <a href="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/101/ogvs/holga.ogv"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="disc_content/video/retro_photography_effects/holga.mov" /><img src="images/video/image2.jpg" style="margin-bottom:21px;"></a>
            <a href="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/101/ogvs/holga.ogv"></a>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>

    <!-- /playlist -->

    <!-- /video -->

<div class="span9">
    <video id="video" width="960" height="600" controls="controls"  autoplay="autoplay">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="disc_content/video/retro_photography_effects/holga.mov" />
        <source type="video/ogg" src="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/101/ogvs/holga.ogv" />
        <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie"> <img src="images/generic/vid_holder.png" alt="html5 video error" width="640" height="360" /></a>
        <p> Your video tag is not supported</p>
    </video>                      
</div>        


    <!-- /video -->

**Javascript**
<!-- Video Playlist START -->

var video;
var playlist;
var tracks;
var current;


init();
function init(){
    current = 0;
    video = $('#video');
    playlist = $('#playlist');
    tracks = playlist.find('li a');
    len = tracks.length - 1;
    video[0].volume = .60;
    video[0].play();
    playlist.find('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this);
        current = link.parent().index();
        run(link, video[0]);
    });
    video[0].addEventListener('ended',function(e){
        current++;
        if(current == len){
            current = 0;
            link = playlist.find('a')[0];
        }else{
            link = playlist.find('a')[current];    
        }
        run($(link),video[0]);
    });
}
function run(link, player){
        player.src = link.attr('href');
        par = link.parent();
        par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        video[0].load();
        video[0].play();
}

<!-- Video Playlist END -->
```

Comment: try http://videojs.com/ or http://sublimevideo.net/ easy to add and use.
i prefer videojs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am looking to use video.js as my fallback platform. But I am building my own controls, loading bars etc so am hoping I can get this Javascript fallback code to work and manipulate all the HTML5 features myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
**HTML**
<!-- /playlist -->

<div class="span2">
 <ul id="playlist">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="disc_content/video/retro_photography_effects/film_burn.mov" rel="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/101/ogvs/holga.ogv"/><img src="images/video/image1.jpg" style="margin-bottom:21px;"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="disc_content/video/retro_photography_effects/holga.mov" rel="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/101/ogvs/holga.ogv" /><img src="images/video/image2.jpg" style="margin-bottom:21px;"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="disc_content/video/retro_photography_effects/holga.mov" rel="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/101/ogvs/holga.ogv" /><img src="images/video/image2.jpg" style="margin-bottom:21px;"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="disc_content/video/retro_photography_effects/holga2.mov" rel="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/102/ogvs/holga.ogv" /><img src="images/video/image2.jpg" style="margin-bottom:21px;"></a>
    </li>   
</ul>
</div>
<!-- /playlist -->
<!-- /video -->div class="span9">
<video id="video" width="960" height="600" controls="controls"  autoplay="autoplay">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="disc_content/video/retro_photography_effects/holga.mov" />
    <source type="video/ogg" src="http://www.advancedphotoshop.co.uk/discs/101/ogvs/holga.ogv" />
    <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie"> <img src="images/generic/vid_holder.png" alt="html5 video error" width="640" height="360" /></a>
    <p> Your video tag is not supported</p>
</video>                      
</div>      
<!-- /video -->





//Javascript
function run(link, player){
    $(player).children().eq(0).attr("src",link.attr('href'));
    $(player).children().eq(1).attr("src",link.attr('rel'));
    par = link.parent();
    par.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    video[0].load();
    video[0].play();
 }
```

I have changed your HTML a little bit and then i have changed the "run()" function to replace both the source tags.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it! Unfortunately I still cannot get the video to load in Safari. I am using version 5.1.7, this may be the cause if you are not having this issue. It seems to be looking for the right video but it just won't load it within the video tag.

Comment: It works.... you need to specify full path for mov file try replacing all the href's with http://trailers.apple.com/movies/independent/thethieves/thethieves-tlr1_480p.mov

Comment: What version of Safari are you using? I get the initial video tag loading the first video, but then when I click on the thumbnail images for a different video it doesn't load in. It just shows the controls and no video. I tried replacing all the href links with the Apple Trailers link you supplied and still no joy : (

Comment: I am on Windows Safari 5.1.4. Do you want me to host the HTML code somewhere?

Comment: Yes please, that would be great. That way i could check through the code and see if it is a browser compatability issue. Thank you very much for your help, it is much appreciated!